# Using InteractJS Library does not have behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem when trying to use the library as [InteractJS](http://interactjs.io/).

Right now [my code](https://jsfiddle.net/FMCalisto/nkhp067r/), as you can see, is invoking the files required to successfully complete the example:

```
<link href = "css/drag-drop.css" rel = "stylesheet">
```

and

```
<script src = "js/drag-drop.js"> </ script>
```

However the behavior is not the same I expected since the elements apear on the page but I do not have interaction with them.

The **HTML** code is as shown on page:

```
<div id = "no-drop" class = "drag-drop draggable"> # no-drop </ div>
    
<div id = "yes-drop" class = "drag-drop draggable"> # yes-drop </ div>
    
<div id = "outer-dropzone" class = "dropzone">

    # outer-dropzone
    <div id = "inner-dropzone" class = "dropzone"> # inner-dropzone </ div>
    
</ div>
```

I can not understand what am I doing wrong.

Comment: I doubt the library "Does not work"

Comment: The point was not the fact that the library was not working but the fact that I can't make it work. I changed the tittle in that way, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to add the relevant javascript to perform what you need. In your case, since you are starting from one of the examples:

```
// target elements with the "draggable" class
interact('.draggable')
  .draggable({
    // enable inertial throwing
    inertia: true,
    // keep the element within the area of it's parent
    restrict: {
      restriction: "parent",
      endOnly: true,
      elementRect: { top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 1, right: 1 }
    },

    // call this function on every dragmove event
    onmove: dragMoveListener,
    // call this function on every dragend event
    onend: function (event) {
      var textEl = event.target.querySelector('p');

      textEl && (textEl.textContent =
        'moved a distance of '
        + (Math.sqrt(event.dx * event.dx +
                     event.dy * event.dy)|0) + 'px');
    }
  });

  function dragMoveListener (event) {
    var target = event.target,
        // keep the dragged position in the data-x/data-y attributes
        x = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-x')) || 0) + event.dx,
        y = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-y')) || 0) + event.dy;

    // translate the element
    target.style.webkitTransform =
    target.style.transform =
      'translate(' + x + 'px, ' + y + 'px)';

    // update the posiion attributes
    target.setAttribute('data-x', x);
    target.setAttribute('data-y', y);
  }

  // this is used later in the resizing demo
  window.dragMoveListener = dragMoveListener;


    // enable draggables to be dropped into this
    interact('.dropzone').dropzone({
      // only accept elements matching this CSS selector
      accept: '#yes-drop',
      // Require a 75% element overlap for a drop to be possible
      overlap: 0.75,

      // listen for drop related events:

      ondropactivate: function (event) {
        // add active dropzone feedback
        event.target.classList.add('drop-active');
      },
      ondragenter: function (event) {
        var draggableElement = event.relatedTarget,
            dropzoneElement = event.target;

        // feedback the possibility of a drop
        dropzoneElement.classList.add('drop-target');
        draggableElement.classList.add('can-drop');
        draggableElement.textContent = 'Dragged in';
      },
      ondragleave: function (event) {
        // remove the drop feedback style
        event.target.classList.remove('drop-target');
        event.relatedTarget.classList.remove('can-drop');
        event.relatedTarget.textContent = 'Dragged out';
      },
      ondrop: function (event) {
        event.relatedTarget.textContent = 'Dropped';
      },
      ondropdeactivate: function (event) {
        // remove active dropzone feedback
        event.target.classList.remove('drop-active');
        event.target.classList.remove('drop-target');
      }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you but it still have no behavior.

Comment: It really was one of the problems.